# Nodejs body-parser or request sending stream of compressed json

Tags: node.js, zlib, body-parser

Is it wise to send stream of zlib stream directly to rest api created in nodejs should we encode it before sending?

secondly I am not able to find any code sample to inflate compressed stream to rest api can body-parser does that but we hv multiple endpoints some accept json and some compressed json

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
```

what needs to be done server file?

Comment: try use -> app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    limit: '50mb',
    extended: true
  }));

Comment: can I use all 3 together  app.use(bodyParser.json({ verify: rawBodySaver }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ verify: rawBodySaver, extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.raw({ verify: rawBodySaver, type: function () { return true } }));